# Color opacity in Android XML

Tags: android, color-codes

Android color code is 8-digit hex code like #ff123456. First 2 digits are for opacity and rest of them are the general RGB color code. And the opacity value is optional assuming it is 0xff.

My question is, for a given color value, say:

```
<color name="vivid_red">#ffff0000</color>
```

Or

```
<color name="vivid_red">#ff0000</color>
```

Can I set a color with opacity 50% by referring a color value `vivid_red`, or should I define different color codes while their RGB parts are all the same, but only opacity parts are different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's XML, it will only be able to distinguish what you mean in your usage by the name of the element, unless you have some other code that parses the `color` element for a particular `name` attribute.

So,

```
<color name="vivid_red">#ff0000</color>
```

and

```
<color name="vivid_red_half_trans">#80ff0000</color>
```